# Google won't display site

Tags: google, ranking, noindex

My website (http://markasoftware.getenjoyment.net) doesn't seem to be indexed properly by Google (I haven't tried other search engines).

When I type in the URL of my site it appears right at the top of the list like it should. When I type in the entire contents of the title, however, the site doesn't appear!

The title is quite long

> Thermonuclear War Game Online: Thermonuclear War By Mark

and it has little (if any) competition.

Have I been punished by Google for some reason, or is it something else? I have received zero hits from search engines. Can someone tell me why my site doesn't appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only really have one page in the site and that page doesn't have a great deal of content on it. I appreciate there is an about page, but that isn't coded properly and has no meta description so google is ignoring it.

My advice would be:-

- Write more content (game tutorials, a blog, high score pages and so on)
- Make sure your HTML is well formed and SEO friendly)
- Add proper main navigation
- Implement a CMS like Wordpress (wordpress is built for better SEO)

Comment: Agreed on all points

Comment: I am currently working on upgrades which include a multiplayer version of the game, therefore I will need acounts so there will be create account, login, and many other pages with FAQ and I am planning to eventually make another game.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that the you are just not ranking that high with the words in your title.

There are a lot of links to sites like "Global Thermonuclear War", "online war game", and things like that that are ranking above your site.

Comment: then what should my keywords be?

Comment: It may be hard to figure out keywords for your title. It may be a good idea to give your game a unique name, and start promoting it under that name. With a unique name your game title should be the top results on Google when people search for you.

Comment: only problem is that nobody would search for my game title because less than 50 people know about it and they use the URL, not a search engine, to find my site.

Comment: Well, now may be the best time to come up with a unique title for it, before you have a lot of visitors. It also takes time to build up a user base as well, so try to get your game listed on an online gaming website and things like that. But without a unique name you're likely to have trouble being found in a search engine.